# SMTP on Azure VM - Public IPs (PIP) and Reverse DNS lookups

Tags: azure, smtp, ip, pip, public

Azure recently introduced PIP - Public IPs that can be assigned to Virtual Machine instances,  however it appears that there is no way to assign a PTR record to that IP so that a reverse DNS lookup will be successful. Here are the instructions to assign a PIP to an Azure VM:

https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/

We have VMs on Rackspace Cloud running SMTP services that I'm trying to duplicate on Azure, but there appears to be no way to assign a PTR record for your Azure PIP.  As a result, we are unable to provide our own SMTP service on Azure. Rackspace Cloud assigns a public IP address, and allows you to edit their DNS PTR records for that IP address and assign it to your service.  Is there any way to do something similar with Azure?

BTW:  SendGrid and Amazon SES are not an option. We've been running E-mail servers for decades responsibly, unless we can get a VM with a public IP and DNS setup properly, Azure isn't a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

The name resolution service provided by Azure is mainly designed to access virtual machines and role instances within a cloud service by hostname directly.

To access your public endpoints by name in this case, I recommend deploying your own (using your existing) DNS server(s) with all the flexibility it offers for creating A, MX, PTR etc. records.

For more information on name resolution scenarios, please review https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/.

Comment: Thanks Tom, but Reverse DNS is not as simple as running DNS on an Azure server or from an external DNS server. Reverse DNS is the opposite of forward DNS, it looks up an IP address and sees what domain is associated with it. Microsoft owns the IP addresses that it assigns to their VMs and Cloud services and they don't assign PTR records to the IPs that you reserve when you use powershell to reserve a PIP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690118.aspx) Nor do they have a method to assign a PTR record for your PIP when you buy it.

Comment: That is indeed true. The IP address owner is the one who can control the PRT records and in this case that would be Microsoft.

Comment: @jbraun have you had any luck with this? I also need a PTR record for the PIP I've recently assigned to my VM. Previously we used the cloud service VIP with a PTR record successfully, but needed to add a PIP to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Now to the **good news**: I just learned that this is something they are actually working on right now!

Have a look here http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking-dns-traffic-manager-vpn-vnet/suggestions/3090834-provide-reverse-dns-ptr-records-for-virtual-mach

Comment: here it is: http://blog.azure.com/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

Answer (score 0):

Announcing: Reverse DNS for Azure Cloud Services

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

Enjoy....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the outgoing IP is different then the VIP one for which you create the reverse unfortunately